# Regex match case and ignore rest of file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I was hoping someone could show me the right way to match letters/digits from my text. I just can't get it right.

I would like to match the date after the word "until" in a html file I am searching.

```
string old;
string FileName = "info.html";
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(FileName);

while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(old, @"(?<=until\s)\d+-\w{3}-\d{2}");

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        string key = match.Value;
        label1.Text = key;
        Console.WriteLine(key);         
    }       
}

sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your date string is of constant format, use the following regex

```
(?<=until\s)\d[2]-[A-Za-z]+-\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
\d+-\w{3}-\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Match(s,@"(?<=until\s)\d+[2]-\w+-\d+").Value
```